# Button to stop infinite scroll in search result listing?

Tags: search-results, infinite-scroll, lazy-loading

One of the problems of using infinite scroll on a search result listing page is that the user never can get to the bottom/footer of the page (or any other content after the listing) as long as there are more search results available.

I'm planning to let the user stop the loading of more search results and go to the bottom by clicking a button floating over the list at the bottom of the screen. (Like one of those back-to-top buttons.)

I haven't seen this function anywhere and can't find any information here. Has anyone seen a similar solution? Can you spot any obvious problems?

Comment: You could always let them add one more page-worth of results at a time with a "show more results" button - a much more commonplace pattern

Answer (score 2):

> In general, infinite scroll works well for something like
>   Twitter/Instagram where users consuming an endlessly flowing stream of
>   data without looking for anything in particular.

Source: https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1

Infinite scroll in search results is iffy because users *are* looking for specific results.

You can use a 'load more' or 'show more' button. Clicking this will open the next batch of search results, giving more control over how much is viewed at a time. However, you may want to consider going to pagination if you implement it like this in search results. Doing that also helps the user find the result back if they decide to continue browsing for a while (page 4 is easier to remember and recognize than 'somewhere on 2/3rd of the page).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But I've already considered pagination and "load more" options. The specific questions I have are related to the infinite scroll function.

Comment: The way you phrased your solution makes me wonder if people will get confused. It sounds like the opposite of what would be expected ('stop loading' instead of 'load more'). I have not seem something like that in the wild yet either. You should test it if you have the means to :-)

Comment: Wanda, you're right. The non-conventional ux will require the design/communication to be really clear, not to confuse the user. But I think it's strange I haven't come across something like this at all. (Or maybe it's just a sign that the solution the idea is really bad. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Very fewer people want to see footer section of the page so why give "load more" for fewer one. Infinite scroll obviously hurt those fewer of them when they have not reached footer section.

stopping infinite scroll by giving button to see footer section is not wisely solution.

There is another alternative I have seen and I think that's the perfect solution without losing anything.

Instead of stopping infinite page load just add button to show footer.

Like this [image]

once clik on about button which is place extream bottom right show the footer 
[image]

Get here the working example polyvore.com/dresses/shop?category_id=3

Comment: Iliyas, I agree. In the actual scenario on this page, accessing the footer is a secondary action. Thanks for the link!